# Is there any IID_XXX to get focused tab from Internet Explorer?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc

I am working on one project where I want to inject a script in currently visited web page in web browser. I have written following code for the same.

```
        IDispatch *spDisp;
    HRESULT hR;
    IHTMLWindow2 *pWnd      = NULL;
    IWebBrowser2 *spBrowser = NULL;
    IHTMLDocument2 *spDoc   = NULL;
for (long i = 0; i < nCount; i++){
    _variant_t va(i, VT_I4);
    hR = m_spSHWinds->Item(va, &spDisp);
    if(hR != S_OK)
       continue;
    hR =spDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&spBrowser);
    spDisp->Release();
    if (hR == S_OK)
    {
    hR = spBrowser->get_LocationName(&str);
    hR = spBrowser->get_LocationURL(&str);
    hR = spBrowser->get_Document((IDispatch**)&spDisp);
       hR = spDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)&spDoc);
       spDisp->Release();                       
    if(hR == S_OK){
        hR = spDoc->get_URL(&str);
    }   
  }
}
```

here the `m_spSHWinds` is an object of `IShellWindowsPtr m_spSHWinds;`and initialized as `m_spSHWinds.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ShellWindows));`
But the Problem is that. It is giving me handle of all the web pages in a sequence of there tabs in IE browser. but I need only the currently selected tab from the all.

Can any one tell me how can I do that?
Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: What is triggering execution of your code?

Comment: sorry I am not able understand your question...

Comment: Is the code in your question triggered by an user action? Or is it running in background, and if so what activates it?

Comment: this is activated by user action in my application. On button click event.

Comment: Then, at that moment, there is no focused tab. what you want to know is "what was the last focused tab, even if that was one hour ago"?

Comment: yes, right I need the same.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Don't forget that a global hook needs to be in a DLL.

Comment: yeah I have developed it for my application and it works fine now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I would do that:

Install a global [WH_CALLWNDPROC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx#wh_callwndproc_wh_callwndprocret) hook.

In the hook procedure, filter for messages sent to Windows of the class "`Internet Explorer_Server`", and filter for the message [WM_SETFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646283.aspx).

When you detect a focus event, use [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) to signal it to your program, using `lParam` for carrying the `HWND`. Do that only for focus gain, not focus loss.

The `HWND` to which you'll PostMessage may be known via [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499.aspx). It's one of the windows of your main program.

Beware the Low Level Integrity for the IE process hosting your hook. On recent version of IE and on recent version of Windows, your `PostMessage` may fail with error "Access Denied". To overcome that, you will have to use [ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388202.aspx). Warning: if you target Windows Vista, you must use [ChangeWindowMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632675.aspx). Best way to deal with that is to dynamically query the availability of the APIs via [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) on `user32.dll`, starting with the `Ex` version, falling back to the old one. If neither are present, don't bother, you are on XP (or lower).

You are now able to store in your main program the `HWND` of the last focused IE rendering window, and that should work for any version of IE.

You may add `WM_DESTROY` to your hook filter, and notify your main program, as you may want to address the case in which the last focused tab is closed.

When the user click on your button, use the "`WM_HTML_GETOBJECT`" Registered Window Message and the `ObjectFromLresult` API to obtain an `IHTMLDocument2` interface pointer. See [How to get IHTMLDocument2 from a HWND](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249232/en-us).